# Pegar descrição select - AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Tenho esta função e preciso carregar a descrição mesmo do select. Nesta função consigo carregar apenas o id, como posso fazer para no lugar do x(que é o id) eu pegue a descrição?

```
 function myFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
            var url = "/ContaApagar/CarregaValor";

            $.ajax({
                url: url
                , data: { id: x }
                , type: "POST"
                , datatype: "html"
                , success: function (data) {
                    if (data.resultado > 0) {
                        $("#txtValor").val(data.valor);
                    }
                }
            });


        }
```

Gostaria de jogar a descrição neste campo:

```
 <textarea asp-for="ContasApagarVM.ContasApagar.Obs" class="form-control" id="demo"></textarea>
```

Por isto eu preciso do nome, além do value.
Aqui está a função do controller CarregaValor.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CarregaValor( int id, decimal valor)
    {

        var item =  _context.Receitas.Where( r => r.Id == id && r.Tipo == "D").First();
        return Json(new
        {
            valor = item.Valor
           // var teste = valor
        });


    }
```

Comment: Mas o `id` você está usando pra fazer a requisição, certo? Você gostaria de fazer a requisição pela descrição?

Comment: Editei a pergunta, eu preciso da descrição para jogá-la em outro campo.

Comment: A descrição, no caso, seria o texto contido na opção do `select`?

Comment: Isso, coloquei também a função do controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para pegar o text da opção selecionada:

```
var texto = $("#mySelect option:selected").text();
```

Para jogar isso para o controller, altere o objeto data para:

```
data: {id: x, text: texto},
```

Adicione o parâmetro adicional no controller

```
public ActionResult CarregaValor( int id, string text, decimal valor)
```

Para jogar o texto no textarea:

```
$("#demo").text(texto);
```

Answer (score 1):

No snippet abaixo, a função recupera o texto da `<option>` escolhida dentro do seu select. Feito isso, basta gravar o texto na tag que desejar!

```js
function myFunction(){
   var x = document.getElementById('mySelect').value
   var texto = $(`#mySelect option:selected`).text()
   $('#demo').text(`You selected ${texto}`)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='mySelect' onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value='1'>Opção 1</option>
  <option value='2'>Opção 2</option>
</select>
<textarea asp-for="ContasApagarVM.ContasApagar.Obs" class="form-control" id="demo"></textarea>
```